# RabbitMQ publisher confirm order

Tags: rabbitmq

I am writing a wrapper around the .NET RabbitMQ library and have a question that isn't answered in the documentation as far as I can see, and I can't think of a way to verify it experimentally.

The [documentation here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) states the following:

> In most cases, RabbitMQ will acknowledge messages to publishers in the
> same order they were published (this applies for messages published on
> a single channel). However, publisher acknowledgements are emitted
> asynchronously and can confirm a single message or a group of
> messages. The exact moment when a confirm is emitted depends on the
> delivery mode of a message (persistent vs. transient) and the
> properties of the queue(s) the message was routed to (see above).
> Which is to say that different messages can be considered ready for
> acknowledgement at different times. This means that acknowledgements
> can arrive in a different order compared to their respective messages.
> Applications should not depend on the order of acknowledgements when
> possible.

So confirmations can be received out of order which I can cope with OK. However, how does this play with the `Multiple` flag that can be used?

Imagine the following scenario: I send messages 1,2,3,4 and 5. 1 fails and 2-5 succeed. The broker sends me a Nack for 1 and a single Ack for 5 with `Multiple` set to true. If order were guaranteed then I know I would get the Nack for 1 first and then I would know that the Ack was for 2-5. However, if they could be out of order, then I would assume, as I hadn't had a confirm for 1, that the Ack was for 1-5, and then when the Nack came in, it would be too late.

Are there guarantees somewhere where this scenario cannot happen?

Comment: Try also asking this in [RabbitMQ google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/CJjVpRPGu68/Grj5cqrVDgAJ) from the Google Group [mentioned by Alex in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213939/rabbitmq-publisher-confirm-order#comment95255212_54213939). Basically, this scenario can't happen.

> Hi,
>
> If you get a single nack for 1 then an ack for 5 with multiple=true this means 2-5 were all successful.
>
> If 1 is delayed but 2-5 are not you should get 4 multiple=false acks with sequences 2-5 *then* a nack for 1.
>
> It would be nicer if ack frames used ranges instead of the multiple flag but we are where we are.
>
> Cheers
> Karl